# Making all buttons in a column and row the same size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a calculator and i want all the buttons in the rows and columns of my table to align with each other both horizontal and vertical. They align horizontally right now since i have rows but i want to have the same size vertically despite what i put in the button. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

add a specific width in your css

```
input {
   text-align:center;
   width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write your css like this:

```
<style>
td{
  text-align:center;
  }
  button{
    width:100%;
  }
```

and your html like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>BACK</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>C</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>CE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>7</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>8</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>9</button>
      </td>
    </tr> etc ...
```

Then, if you want to use jquery you can use this handy script to make all tds the size of the widest:

```
  $(function(){
    var widest=Math.max($('td').width());
    $('td').width(widest);
  })
```

If you don't want to use jquery use @Abhidevs approach to set a fixed width.

Play around with my version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/veaatXaig1o4brVRT7aJ?p=preview)